# How to use a variable in a variable with a for loop bash script?

Tags: bash

Is it possible to create a variable using a varible? like the script below?

Any help will be apprciated.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..10}
do
dog${i}=test${i}
echo $dog${i}
done
```

making the varible outside of the for loop works but doesnt inside, is there a work around?

I have tried many different uses of brackets and parenthesis but to no success

Comment: Bash supports arrays so it is often possible to avoid using dynamic variable names.  In this case you can make `dog` an array and set elements with `dog[i]=test$i`.  Use `declare -p dog` to show all elements of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..10}
do
  test="dog$i"
  val="test$i"
  declare "$test=$val"
  echo "${!test}"
done
```

Comment: yes it does what i need, cheers

Comment: @Craig Good, Can you mark it as a valid answer?

Comment: Please don't answer duplicate questions.

Comment: @0stone0 Seen many people answer to duplicates in the past, never have I seen them get down voted. Just deleted. The response still answers the question, even though the question might be asked in a other way somewhere else.

Comment: This also works with using the [] brackets: #!/bin/bash

for i in {1..10}
do

dog[$i]=test$i
echo "${dog[$i]}"

#dog=test${i}
#echo $dog

done